# How to put each cell value for each row from GridView in variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I tried some ways in stackoverflow solutions. But Those are not implemented well by me. Most of the time I got null/empty for the variables and Exception like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

My GridView:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="TestReportGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="370px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <%#Eval("TestId") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("TestName") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fee">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("Fee") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to put cell text in 4 different variables for each row when I click in Save button:

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string patient = PatientNameTextBox.Text;
    string birthDate = BirthDateTextBox.Text;
    string mobile = MobileNoTextBox.Text;

    int rows = TestReportGridView.Rows.Count;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in TestReportGridView.Rows)
    {
        Label test = (Label)row.FindControl("Test");
        string testName = test.Text;

        //Label lblQuantity = (Label)row.FindControl("Quantity");
        //string Quantity = lblQuantity.Text;
    }
}
```

[Image of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRYSl.jpg)

---

I added a label in ItemTemplate. does it right way to add Label

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Test" runat="server" ><%#Eval("TestName") %></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: you don't have any label called `Test` in your `ItemTemplate`.  Adding `eval` directly in `ItemTemplate` doesn't create label for you.  You need to add `Label` control and assign `eval` to `Text` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `Label` control in your `ItemTemplate`.  An example below:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Test" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TestName") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Adding `<%#Eval("TestId") %>` directly inside `ItemTemplate` will not automatically add any control to search from code behind.